# Halo 4 graphics are low

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4

I have *Xbox 360 4GB* version(regret that I've bought this version). When I compare graphics of my Halo 4 with Halo 4 multiplayer videos on YouTube, mine is much worse. I've installed some extra data on my **flash drive**. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of TV are you playing on? Do you have an HDMI cable and a TV that can use it?

Comment: Did you buy your Xb360 new or used?

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks How does that matter?

Comment: Just wondering cause if bought used some places let you return it within a certain period.

Comment: I use HDMI cable on my Xbox. I think that the problem is similar to Batlefield 3 HD content pack problem

Comment: @gkiko Wow, you're pretty well-informed. Why did you buy the 4GB version then?

Comment: I got informed after I bought 4Gb version.

Comment: I don't remember downloading an HD pack. But for multiplayer you def need more memory. Are you able to return it?

Comment: No, I bought it 4 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an HD compatible TV with HDMI port to take full advantage of Halo 4s high definition graphics. Also see if you can return that 4gb XB360(if bought recently) for one with more memory.